# How do I build a PC Into a Mac PPC G5 case?

Tags: mac, powerpc, motherboard, pc, g5

How can I convert my (unfortunately) obsolete Mac G5 PPC case into a PC? It only supports Leopard OS-wise and I'd like to keep the beautiful Mac Case and reuse it with PC components inside.

Can that be done? Can the hardware inside be replaced with a PC motherboard etc?

Comment: If you flip this question around - it's more about the skill and familiarity with doing custom computer assembly of you, the person doing the work. It seems less about an Apple product since you could substitute "pretty cardboard box" or "antique vanity chest" for G5 and the question is essentially the same. Would you like help editing this so it works better here?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for asking a question! This really is not on-topic here. This would be better on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com). Please flag your post (there's a button next to the "edit" button) and request that it be migrated to SuperUser. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, and instructions are probably outside the scope of this forum due to the extreme variations and nature of the hardware available.

But heres a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKPBMhQP2Zw) of one guy's journey to turning a G5 case into a hackintosh so you can see what is involved before you make the decision.

And another more detailed tale [here](http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=200555) again not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to purchase a smaller computer that fits inside.  If you do a google search for "atom pc" you'll find a lot of options of reasonably useful machines that will readily fit into the G5 case.  You won't be able to use the original slots for cards, but you should be able to extend SATA cables outside the atom pc to the drives, and attach the power button wire to the correct spot on the atom PC.  You can also extend the USB ports to the outside of the G5 case.

It's not ideal, but for a quick hack that's easier than a full PC upgrade, it's cheaper and easier if you merely want the  design aesthetic.

Answer (score 0):

To the question regarding whether one put can a PC motherboard in G5 tower: the answer is yes.

I placed a gigabyte ga-945gcmx-s2 with 6700 intel into the G5 (it was one I took out of a tower I was updating). The G5 was one that I found at a Goodwill store. There was nothing inside except a fried motherboard. It has four 120mm fans which I added. You will have to rewire the switch but the computer now lights up and turns on. It also has a 500w power supply.

This is my first attempt at something like this. I am planning to upgrade the processor to i7 next month. By the way, I recommend that you do some planning before doing any cutting. That is something I wish I would have done.